# why won't spring-mvc dispatcherservlet kick in?

Tags: java, web-applications, spring-mvc

I'm simply trying to setup my first spring-mvc application so I can play around with the framework.

However, going to this url: localhost:8080/springmvctest/home I get a 404 error. However, going to localhost:8080/springmvctest I do see the welcome page (index.jsp)

What am I doing wrong here?

Web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>springmvctest</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> 
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

app-config.xml

```
<!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
<context:component-scan base-package="controller" />

<!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Resolves view names to protected .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/home","/","/index"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

home.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello home!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

My file structure

```
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── com
│   │   │       └── something
│   │   │           └── springmvctest
│   │   │               ├── testclass.java
│   │   │               └── TestController.java
│   │   └── webapp
│   │       ├── index.jsp
│   │       └── WEB-INF
│   │           ├── app-config.xml
│   │           ├── jsp
│   │           │   └── home.jsp
│   │           └── web.xml
│   └── test
│       └── java
│           └── com
│               └── something
│                   └── springmvctest
```

Answer (score 0):

This pattern

```
<url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
```

only makes math expressions ending in htm and this url:

```
localhost:8080/springmvctest/home
```

not ending htm therefore it is not taken by the dispatcher of spring.

**Solutions:**

Change

```
   <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
```

to

```
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

**Or**

in your controls use

@RequestMapping(value = {"/home.htm","/index.htm"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)